# DDD: University as an aggregate root

Tags: domain-driven-design

For some time I am dealing with Domain-Driven Design. Unfortunately I have some problems regarding the Aggregate.

Say, I like to model the structure of an university. The university has some departments (faculties) and every department has some classes. There is a rule that every department needs to be unique and so every class in it. For instance the names of the classes needs to be unique. If I understand it right, then "University" seems to be my aggregate root and "department" and "class" are entities within this aggregate.

There is another aggregate root "Professor", because they are globally accessible. They will be assigned to a class. I´m unsure if it is allowed because an aggregate root should only point to another aggregate root and not to its content.

How to handle this?
Appreciate your help,
thanks in advance!

Comment: If your domain stops at creating Universities and Classes and assigning Professors to Classes, I wouldn't use the DDD tactical patterns for it. It's basically CRUD. Aggregates can only be designed in the light of more complex use cases and transactional analysis (and I guess end users don't rush to add more Universities or assign Professors in a highly concurrent way every day)

Comment: "Aggregates can only be designed in the light of more complex use cases" That's an odd way to put it. ARs may not be the best fit for simple problems, but they surely can be designed to solve them as well.

Answer (score 3):

> Say, I like to model the structure of an university. The university has some departments (faculties) and every department has some classes. There is a rule that every department needs to be unique and so every class in it. For instance the names of the classes needs to be unique.

Really?  why?  What's the business value of that rule?  What does it cost the business (the university) if there happen to be two classes with the same name.  Does that mean the same name across all time, or just during a given semester?

Part of the point of DDD is that the design of the solution requires exploration of the "ubiquitous language" to get a full understanding of the requirement.

In other words, you may be having trouble finding a good fit for this requirement in the design because you haven't yet discovered all of the entities that you need to make it work the way the business experts expect.

[Udi Dahan](https://gojko.net/2010/06/11/udi-dahan-the-biggest-mistakes-teams-make-when-applying-ddd/) points out that the uniqueness rule may not belong in the domain at all:

> Rules that are not part of genuine domain logic do not have to be implemented in the domain model, suggested he, because they do not model the domain.

So if you have a constraint like this, but the constraint isn't a consequence of the domain itself, then the constraint can be correctly implemented elsewhere.

Greg Young has also written about [set validation](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/08/12/eventual-consistency-and-set-validation/), specifically addressing concerns about eventual consistency.

But broadly, yes -- if you really have a collection of entities, and a domain rules that span multiple elements in the collection, then you need some aggregate that maintains the integrity of the boundary that the collection lives in.

The entities aren't necessarily what you think.  For instance, if you need names to be unique, and the rest of the class entity is just along for the ride, then you may be able to simplify the rules by creating a name registry aggregate; Professors *reserve* names for their classes, and if the reservation is available, then the reserved name can be applied to the class entity.

If your core business really were naming things, with lots of special invariants to consider, you might build out a big model around this.  But that's not particularly likely; perhaps you can just slap a table or two into a relational database -- that's a good solution for a set validation problem -- and get on with the valuable part of the project.

> There is another aggregate root "Professor", because they are globally accessible. They will be assigned to a class. I´m unsure if it is allowed because an aggregate root should only point to another aggregate root and not to its content.

```
class.assign(professorId);
```

is the usual sort of answer here -- you pass around the surrogate key that identifies the aggregate root.  Every entity in your domain should have one.

A couple of cautions here: I have found that real world entities (people, in particular) aren't a useful starting point for figuring out what aggregates are for.  Primarily, because they end up being representations, primarily, of data where the invariant is enforced outside the domain model.

Also, I've found that starting from the nouns - class, department, professor - tends to put the focus on CRUD, which generally isn't a very interesting problem.

Instead, I recommend thinking about doing something useful -- a use case where there are business rules to enforce, when the business model gets to say "no, the business won't let you do that right now".

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself these questions:

- How many universities will be in your system? If this is only one, it is not your aggregate root.
- If you have multiple universities in your system, would be someone working across universities? May be universities are your system tenants?
- What happens with a class if some department is dissolved? Will it immediately disappear? I doubt it.
- The same as above with university to department relationship

It is not a problem with a Department to hold reference to its classes as a list of value objects that will contain the Class aggregate root id and the class name. The same is valid for departments dealing with their classes.

Vernon's [Effective Aggregate Design](https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=838) might help too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I haven't seen it this way. So department and class are aggregate roots. I have read Vernon's documents many times, but  I don't have much experience with DDD yet. Some concepts are difficult to understand when they are biased by experiences before DDD (anemic domain model, technical concerns regarding persistence). :-)

Comment: Definitely, I would make Department and Class as separate aggregates since they are of different origin and serve different purposes. It is not very often you really need other entities inside your aggregate except of the aggregate root entity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very experienced in DDD either but here some tips I use to use:

- Is it possible to have a Class without a Department assigned? If that is the case then the Department is the aggregate root and Class is another aggregate with a reference to the root, the Department. You can even define a factory method "addClass()" within your Department with the info that a Class needs to be created, so nobody should be allowed to create a Class without a Department.

Why defining a Class a an Aggregate instead of a Value Object? Because Value Objects are distinguished by their properties' value rather than an ID. I would say that even having two Classes with the same name, same students, same info, etc, etc. the business would still want to differentiate each one. It is not the same with a 1 cent coin which with you only care about the value (given by the color, size, weight,...) but you can always replace it with another one with same attributes' value, that is 1 cent. Also assigning another Professor to the class, the class remains the same, it is not immutable as a Value Object should be.

- I guess a Professor must be uniquely identified, and he can maybe be assigned to different Classes or even Departments. So to me it is another Aggregate root separated from the department.